# Set Values A Select with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have a table with inputs, radiobuttons and select, these  can be cloned with a button through javascript which inserts HTML through an .after. The reason of my question is that at the moment of creating the Select it has to fill with the information in database, and javascript is not allowing to insert PHP as in HTML.

I would like to know what do you recommend me to do to make the Select gets filled at the moment that I insert the new table row.

It should follow the following logic (I understand that it is wrong this way):

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var cloneCount = 1;            

            $("#añadirEjercicio").on('click', function() {
                cloneCount++;
                $("#tabla tbody tr:last").after('<tr class="fila-fija">' +
                    '<td><select class="form-control" id="ejercicio" name="ejercicio[]" required>'+
                                        '<optgroup label="Seleccionar un ejercicio">'+
                                        <?php
                                            //ADMINISTRADOR
                                            $consulta = "SELECT * FROM Ejercicios";
                                            $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
                                            $listaEjercicios = $resultado;
                                            $filas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

                                            while ($rowEjercicio = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
                                                $nombreEjercicio =  $rowEjercicio['nombre'];
                                                $IdEjercicio = $rowEjercicio['IdEjercicio'];
                                                echo "<option value='$IdEjercicio'>$IdEjercicio-$nombreEjercicio </option>";
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        '</optgroup>'+
                                    '</select></td>'+
                    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="duracion1[]" name="duracion1[]" required ></td>' +
                    '<td>' +
                    '<div class="form-check form-check-inline">' +
                    '<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="circuito" name="clasificacion' + cloneCount + '" value="Circuito" >' +
                    '<label class="form-check-label" for="circuito">Circuito</label>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="form-check form-check-inline">' +
                    '<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="bloque" name="clasificacion' + cloneCount + '" value="Bloque" >' +
                    '<label class="form-check-label" for="bloque">Bloque</label>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="form-check form-check-inline">' +
                    '<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="intervalo" name="clasificacion' + cloneCount + '" value="Intervalo" >' +
                    '<label class="form-check-label" for="intervalo">Intervalos</label>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="duracion2[]" name="duracion2[]" required ></td>' +
                    '<td>' +
                    '<div class="form-check form-check-inline">' +
                    '<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="serie[]" name="serie[]" value="Series" >' +
                    '<label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Series</label>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="form-check form-check-inline">' +
                    '<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="repeticion[]" name="repeticion[]" value="Repeticiones" >' +
                    '<label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Repeticiones</label>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</td>');
            });

        })
    </script>
```

Comment: I would recommend that you take a look at `AJAX`. That's probably your best bet with your current logic.

Comment: Any idea how to implement it within the after? :/

Comment: Yes, you simply call the AJAX function inside it. `.after( myAjax() );`. You probably have to restructure some things and whatnot, but it's probably the closest thing to your current logic.